# How to search compulsory fields for android layout view (components)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and stuck with repetitive error of attribute of some field (component in layout view) is missing. I add that component and it's good to go. I am having a question with which are compulsory fields for that component? Like in in HTML tag consider  an Anchor tag. 'href' is compulsory. In some other tag 'id' is compulsory. Like same way here. Is there any way we can get for which component - what attributes are compulsory?

I am searching with android documents...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

but can't figure it out. Hope some comments are helpful here.

Thanks.